# If a generalized coordinate is not cyclic, can we conclude that the corresponding generalized momentum is not conserved?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws

This is basically the reverse situation to the normal case: We find a cyclic coordinate in the lagrangian function describing the system and can conclude that the corresponding generalized momentum obeys a conservation law. My question is whether we can derive from a non-cyclic variable, that the momentum is indeed not conserved.

Comment: Of course. Non the less, not all conserved quantities come from cyclic coordinates. See Noether's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generic initial conditions, the answer is *Yes,* due to Lagrange equations
$$ \frac{dp_i}{dt}~\approx~ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i}, \qquad p_i~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}. $$
[Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eom.]